# Manage activity methods when switching a tab using tabHost in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

I am trying to find a way to get the instance of the activity that is running in each tab in tabHost. To be more specific, I have a layout where on top there is a spinner that displays some active football games. Right below there is a tabhost that holds three tabs. Each of the tabs must hove some info about the selected game in the spinner.

So, when I select a different game in the spinner I want the information in the tabs to be changed in order to display the right info about the selected game.

The code that I use in order to create the three tabs:

```
    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.couponTabHost);
    LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);


    TabSpec pointCouponSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Σημεία");
    pointCouponSpec.setIndicator("Σημεία", getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float));
    Intent pointCouponIntent = new Intent(this, CouponPoints.class);
    pointCouponIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    pointCouponIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    pointCouponIntent.putExtra("couponGame",currentGame);
    pointCouponSpec.setContent(pointCouponIntent);

    TabSpec scoreCouponSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Σκορ");
    scoreCouponSpec.setIndicator("Σκορ", getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float));
    Intent scoreCouponIntent = new Intent(this, CouponScores.class);
    scoreCouponIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    scoreCouponIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    scoreCouponIntent.putExtra("couponGame", currentGame);
    scoreCouponSpec.setContent(scoreCouponIntent);

    TabSpec systemCouponSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Συστήματα");
    systemCouponSpec.setIndicator("Συστήματα", getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float));
    Intent systemCouponIntent = new Intent(this, CouponSystems.class);
    systemCouponIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    systemCouponIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    systemCouponIntent.putExtra("couponGame", currentGame);
    systemCouponSpec.setContent(systemCouponIntent);

    tabHost.addTab(pointCouponSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(scoreCouponSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(systemCouponSpec);
```

As you understand I use Intents to create every tab. When an item in the spinner is selected, I change the `currentGame` to have the selected instance of the football game `(setOnItemSelectedListener)`.

What I want now is to get the instance of the active Activity (CouponPoints, CouponScores, CouponSystems) in tabHost, in order to call a specific method that "refreshes" the components in the active tab.

I tried to do something like that by adding the flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and then handling the method `onNewIntent()` in each Coupon* activity... Unfortunately this doesn't work...

Does anyone have any ideas how to refresh my components when a spinner item is selected???

Comment: `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` alone will be enough

Comment: "I am trying to find a way to get the instance of the activity that is running in each tab in tabHost" -- having activities in tabs was deprecated over two years ago.

Comment: @commonsWare Yes I know that (I am used to this way), but still there have to be some way...

Comment: @Pragnami I have a Log.d() in the onNewIntent() method. It doesn't show up in the LogCat... I know that I miss something. Do I have to add some additional attributes in the declaration of every Coupon* method in Manifest that "allows" this method to be called???